# How to use Fubini's theorem to show the integral $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\cos (10x+17y)}{1-xy}dx dy$ exists?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

> Can we use the Fubini's theorem to the following integral: $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\cos (10x+17y)}{1-xy}dx dy$$

My Attempt: It suffices to show that
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left|\cos (10x+17y)\right|}{1-xy}dx dy<\infty .$$

According to Tonelli's theorem, it suffices to show the iterated integral is finite. I think we should somewhat zoom in the fraction then I am stuck. Any hint, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second double integral is non-negative, but bounded above by $$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{dxdy}{1-xy}=\sum_{n\ge 1}\int_0^1\int_0^1(xy)^{n-1}dxdy=\zeta(2).$$